# SoapUI Testsuite √ ReadyAPI Testsuite X (InvocationTargetException@Property Transfer)

Tags: soapui

So I have this testsuite in SoapUI 5.0.0 that runs through without errors.
When I run the same testsuite in Ready!API 1.3.1 it fails in the **property transfer** step after a successful webservice call (I get a valid response).

But it just shows me [**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**] without any further information.

What is going on here and how can I resolve this problem in ReadyAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

I don't know what ReadyAPI does but it seems to have introduced the **path language** which is by default set to XQuery but not for the very first transfer. Manually changing it from XQuery to XPath solved the problem. Hope this helps